# Rails - CanCan - accessible_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, accessible

Can anyone explain to me how CanCan's `accessible_by` works?  How does it know what the relationship is between the user and the thing that needs restricting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancan accessible\_by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344247/cancan-accessible-by)

Answer (score 2):

It checks the current user against a set of rules described in the abilities initializer which includes `CanCan::Ability`. When you call `accessible_by` it checks the rules specifed in the `Ability` class, and returns the records that the user has access to.
The gem's wiki is very good... here: [defining abilities](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities)

Answer (score 1):

There is a great railscast about CanCan (made by its creator):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan