# Cancan accessible_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, cancan

What exactly is happening when I do:

```
@patient.course_enrollments.accessible_by(current_ability)
```

What seems to happen is I get course_enrollments where `course.client_id = user.client.id`, I just don't understand how `accessible_by` works.

```
# ability.rb
can :manage, CourseEnrollment, :course => {:client_id => user.client.id}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`accessible_by` gives you a scope that includes only those records which you'd be able to access given the `current_ability`. Since you stated that the `:manage` ability on `CourseEnrollment` is filtered by courses owned by the current user, the `accessible_by` call will add in that same restriction so that the course enrollments returned will all be "accessible by" the current user.